# Need to ensure the no value columns are counted just like NULLS with COUNT(*)

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I am working on a SQL call to ensure that all columns are counted regardless of NULL or no Value. EDIT I also need it to show that it is O. Currently this is where I am:

```
SELECT q.range AS import_range, COUNT(*) AS num_occurrences
FROM (
  SELECT CASE
   WHEN (new_total-old_total) BETWEEN 100 AND 149 THEN '100-149'
   WHEN (new_total-old_total) BETWEEN 150 AND 199 THEN '150-199'
   WHEN (new_total-old_total) BETWEEN 200 AND 249 THEN '200-249'
   ELSE '250+'
   END AS 'range'
  FROM lists_imports
) q
GROUP BY q.range;
```

I have looked into the null then 0 type formats but I find that since my when column is a equation is having a issue.

this is what I tried:

```
SELECT q.range AS import_range, COUNT(*) AS num_occurrences
FROM (
  SELECT Sum(CASE
   WHEN (new_total-old_total) BETWEEN 100 AND 149 THEN '100-149' when (new_total-old_total) null then 0 else 1 end 
   WHEN (new_total-old_total) BETWEEN 150 AND 199 THEN '150-199' when (new_total-old_total) null then 0 else 1 end 
   WHEN (new_total-old_total) BETWEEN 200 AND 249 THEN '200-249' when (new_total-old_total) null then 0 else 1 end)
   ELSE '250+'
   END AS 'range'
  FROM lists_imports
) q
GROUP BY q.range;
```

I am really new to SQL so sorry if this is easy. I just have really been trying a bit of everything unsuccessfully. The table I am working in does not have NULL so any field that is blank is just overlooked currently.

this is what I get

```
+--------------+-----------------+
| import_range | num_occurrences |
+--------------+-----------------+
| 250+         |               5 |
+--------------+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```

But I need it to be

```
+--------------+-----------------+
| import_range | num_occurrences |
+--------------+-----------------+
| 100-149      |             0 |
| 150-199      |             0 |
| 200-249      |             0 |
| 250+         |             5 |
+--------------+-----------------+
4 rows in set (0.06 sec)
```

Comment: `where someCol is not null`

Comment: Please edit your question and show sample data and desired results.  Also, choose your database -- MySQL or SQL Server?  Not both.

Comment: And remember that columns cannot have "no value". They can be NULL or an empty string but those are values.

Comment: Ok sorry as I stated I am still really new at this. But yes I would be speaking of a blank field.

Comment: I removed the SQL Server tag, as I noticed in one of your comments below an answer that you got a MySQL specific error message.  Be mindful of the tags in the future to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you want `coalesce()`:

```
SELECT q.range AS import_range, COUNT(*) AS num_occurrences
FROM (SELECT (CASE WHEN coalesce(new_total, 0) - coalesce(old_total, 0) BETWEEN 100 AND 149 THEN '100-149'
                   WHEN coalesce(new_total, 0) - coalesce(old_total, 0) BETWEEN 150 AND 199 THEN '150-199'
                   WHEN coalesce(new_total, 0) - coalesce(old_total, 0) BETWEEN 200 AND 249 THEN '200-249'
                   ELSE '250+'
              END) AS `range`
      FROM lists_imports
     ) q
GROUP BY q.range;
```

Comment: When I try that I get ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'range
      FROM lists_imports
     ) q
GROUP BY q.range' at line 6

Comment: I feel this is on the right track just dont know what to change. Can I have a 0 used if nothing is found?

Comment: @JamesMadison . . . `range` is a reserved word -- a bad choice for a column alias.  It should be escaped with backticks, not single quotes.  The latter cause confusion with string literals.

Answer (score 0):

I would write it using the isnull operator:

```
SELECT q.range AS import_range, COUNT(*) AS num_occurrences
FROM (SELECT (CASE WHEN isnull(new_total, 0) - isnull(old_total, 0) BETWEEN 100 AND 149 THEN '100-149'
                   WHEN isnull(new_total, 0) - isnull(old_total, 0) BETWEEN 150 AND 199 THEN '150-199'
                   WHEN isnull(new_total, 0) - isnull(old_total, 0) BETWEEN 200 AND 249 THEN '200-249'
                ELSE '250+'
             END) AS range
      FROM lists_imports
     ) q
GROUP BY q.range;
```

You may want to also consider the limits of your ranges.  i.e. when "old_total" is greater than or equal to "new_total" 
or, when "new_total" minus "old_total" < 100

Comment: Using `coalesce` vs. `isnull` makes no difference here (actually, `isnull` won't work if it turns out OP is using MySQL). And if you take that difference away, this is basically a copy-paste of Gordon's answer.

Answer (score 0):

After a second read, I think I know what you are trying to do. I do not like queries like these. You are using dynamic grouping, however, not all of your preconceived groups values are being encountered in your dataset. This means you will have to apply a "phantom" group values and kludge the counts. If this is a common enough report then please consider adding a `RangeType` table. When you left join "physical" values such as `RangeName` then you don't have to use "phantom" group name values. I would prefer even a temp table if need be.

**RangeValueType**

- RangeName
- RangeMinimum
- RangeMaximum

That being said, here is one way to kludge your data.

```
SELECT q.range AS import_range, COUNT(*)-1 AS num_occurrences
FROM (
  SELECT CASE
   WHEN (new_total-old_total) BETWEEN 100 AND 149 THEN '100-149'
   WHEN (new_total-old_total) BETWEEN 150 AND 199 THEN '150-199'
   WHEN (new_total-old_total) BETWEEN 200 AND 249 THEN '200-249'
   ELSE '250+'
   END AS 'range'
  FROM lists_imports  
  UNION ALL SELECT '100-149' AS range
  UNION ALL SELECT '150-199' AS range
  UNION ALL SELECT '200-149' AS range
  UNION ALL SELECT '250+' AS range  
) q
GROUP BY q.range;
```

Notice the UNION ALL instead of UNION. This will make the count(*)-1 work as duplicates will not be removed in the union.

**Using a Temporary Table**

```
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TempValueRanges (
        RangeName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
        RanegMin INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
        RanegMax INT UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT 0
        NoMax BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
    );

    INSERT INTO TempValueRanges ('100-149',100,149,0);
    INSERT INTO TempValueRanges ('100-149',150,199,0);
    INSERT INTO TempValueRanges ('100-149',200,249,0);
    INSERT INTO TempValueRanges ('100-149',250,NULL,1);

    SELECT 
        Range.RangeName,
        RangeCount=COUNT(*) 
    FROM 
        TempValueRanges Range
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
        (
            SELECT Value=new_total-old_total lists_imports  
        ) AS Values ON (Values.Value BETWEEN Range.RangeMin AND Range.RangeMax) OR (Values.Value>Range.RangeMin AND Range.NoMax=1)
    GROUP BY
        Range.RangeName,

    DROP TABLE TempValueRanges;
```

Comment: I think this is what I needed.. will report back

Comment: not exactly what I needed as I would never have a null field.. I update my need a bit more clear above.. sorry for the confusion

Comment: I updated my answer based on what I think you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Added a possible temp table solution.